# A request for chat.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, chat, moderation

> Related: [Temporary chat for Gaming](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/temporary-chat-for-gaming)

---

This is a feature request for a chat site for gaming to be setup as soon as possible.  The room on the meta site was *extremely* useful in reaching consensus, planning and executing moderation activities.  I'm willing to use the feature in a unstable beta state for the value we got out of it.

---

**Edit**: Note there is already a [temporary irc chat](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/551/temporary-irc-channel-while-the-third-place-goes-live-again) setup.

**Edit**: Chat is back in [public beta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)!  The gamin room can be found [here](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46/gaming) (but you are advised to read the new FAQ first).

Comment: At least for high rep users, this would be really useful. Those 3 days the chat was up, I felt we could "run" the site way better

Comment: There's already a [temporary chatroom](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/551/temporary-irc-channel-while-the-third-place-goes-live-again) set up on IRC.

Comment: I thought badp suggested a place for chatting in http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/551/temporary-irc-channel-while-the-third-place-goes-live-again and I'm sure someone could set up a bot to put RSS updates :)

Comment: @Juan I was only in the gaming room for one day and I felt as though everything worked out far smoother.

Comment: @Oak, the problem with that is that there's no feed, which was very, very useful IMO. We need the official chat!

Comment: @Juan oh yea, that was great.

Comment: not to mention the automatic expansion of certain links... THAT! WAS! LOVELY!

Comment: Getting 20 rep on meta.stackoverflow.com is proving quite difficult, seeing as how I have no problems with or questions the stack engine...:<

Comment: Can anyone list the server/room information so I can join with my own IRC client rather than use a javascript one?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes: Pretty sure the public beta chats are not IRC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the rooms that were active in the meta chat, you now have a [dedicated chat server](http://chat.gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hip hip hooray!